# Setup an A2 canvas

Tags: sketch-app, canvas

I was trying to find a way to set my canvas to an A2 size page so that I can work on it and then submit it to my University (which they are likely to print it in an actual A2 page, therefore it needs to be exact the dimensions of an A2 paper).

The problem is that I haven't find a built-in way to do it, the only possible way I can think of is to set my background picture dimensions but they are in pixels and therefore I am not sure how to calculate exact the dimensions as I am not sure how pixels are working and what PPI I need.

I know about printing in A2 size (setting the dimensions to mm) but I am interesting to create the working canvas into A2 size so I will be sure that what I worked on will be the exact output.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello Rafael and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions about how the site works

Comment: Can't you just set an artboard to the same size as A2?

Comment: @Cai Thanks for you reply. Unfortunately Artboard only support A4, A5, A6 and letter.

Comment: As presets, but you should be able to [resize the artboard yourself](https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/09-grouping/2-artboards.html).

Comment: Also worth noting that if you are only working with vectors, you could design it at any A-size and print at A2.

Comment: @Cai I agree but the problem is that I want to export it in A2 for submission. But I think if I am able to create an A4 artboard I will be able to find out the ppi of the A4 and then therefore of the A2 in pixels.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is... Just change the artboard size to the dimensions of A2. Does that not work?

Comment: @Cai Sorry for not making it clear. I was thinking that depending on your ppi the width and height in pixels differ.

Comment: Ah ok, yes that makes sense. Just decide what PPI you need your artwork in and calculate pixel dimensions from that. There are PPI calculators you can use if you need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketch has preset A size artboards (not A2 though), but you can change the size of your artboard easily enough.

- [Sketch Documentation – Artboards](https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/09-grouping/2-artboards.html)

If you are unsure of the pixel size you need your artboard to be—first decide or ask your printer what PPI your artwork should be, then calculate the dimensions from there.

There are calculators that will help you calculate the dimensions, for example:

- [www.pixelcalculator.com](http://www.pixelcalculator.com/)

For example, A2 is **420 × 594 mm**.

At 300PPI (which is a good assumption for general print work) that is **4961 × 7016 pixels**.

---

There is a Medium article on using Sketch for print design here:

- [Medium – Sketch for Print Design!](https://medium.com/sketch-tricks/sketch-for-print-design-fd165b92cb3a#.n2ukbfoj0)

Comment: [paper sizes in ISO 216](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_216) standard.